# Q: AttributeError: '_FastText' object has no attribute 'most_similar'

Tags: python, facebook, nlp, attributeerror, fasttext

I am using fastText to get similar words.
I have already trained my model, but when I use `model.most_simlar` there is a error.

Here is my code:

```
from pprint import pprint
import gensim
from gensim.models import FastText
pprint(test_model.most_similar('room', topn=10))
```

And here is the error.

```
AttributeError: '_FastText' object has no attribute 'most_similar'
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-24-15ea06598df9> in <module>
      2 import gensim
      3 from gensim.models import FastText
----> 4 pprint(test_model.most_similar('部屋', topn=10))

AttributeError: '_FastText' object has no attribute 'most_similar'
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code doesn't show where your `test_model` object comes from. (Where was it created, trained, or loaded?)

That the error mentions an object of type `_FastText` makes me think it's **not** a Gensim `FastText` model – which isn't named with that leading `_` character. Might it be from some other FastText implementation, such as the Facebook Python wrapper?

If so, that object doesn't have a `.most_similar()` utility method. It looks like that library's examples instead require outside calculations to search for nearby words, such as the `find_nearest_neighbor()` utility function used in this example:

https://github.com/facebookresearch/fastText/blob/a20c0d27cd0ee88a25ea0433b7f03038cd728459/python/doc/examples/compute_accuracy.py#L50

If you wanted to instead use Gensim's `FastText`, you'd want to train your model using only that class, or load a model trained with the Facebook code into that Gensim class, using a function like Gensim's `load_facebook_model()`:

https://radimrehurek.com/gensim/models/fasttext.html#gensim.models.fasttext.load_facebook_model

Then, your model will be of the type `gensim.models.fasttext.FastText`, and have inside its `.wv` property the set of word-vectors, on which operations like `.most_similar()` can be done:

```py
from gensim.models.fasttext import load_facebook_model

ft_model = load_facebook_model(YOUR_PATH_TO_FACEBOOK_BIN_FILE)
print(ft_model.wv.most_similar('部屋')
```